# seaborn pandas factorplot substituting variables in a for loop

Tags: python, pandas, visualization, seaborn

I have been able to succsefully create a seaborn factorplot using the below code, however when I put it in a loop (I want to print factorplots for each column in my dataframe) I get the error: **setting an array element with a sequence**

```
list = ['green','blue','orange']
for i in list:
    print(i)
    sns.factorplot("month_name", [i], "account", sorted_data, col="account",col_wrap=4,sharex=False);
```

What have I done wrong in my for loop? The error I get is:

```
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence
```

Is it possible to orient the x axis so text (month_date) is vertical and not horizontal?

When I try and plot a more human month_name (E.g. Jan, Feb, Mar) seaborn sorts it "August, July, June, October, September) even after I sort by month_date 2014-006-01, 2014-07-01 first?

Comment: Well, for starters, `f` is not defined anywhere in your code.

Comment: hey mwaskom, sorry typo. I find it odd that I can manually replace the (i) value with "green", or "blue" when I copy the line of code and run it separately but it doesn't work in a loop. I've updated the question and added the error I got!

Comment: Why are you passing `i` in a list?

Comment: I was simply trying to pass in a variable i to seaborn to graph the data, I don't know how to do it, that was just a guess.

Comment: rather than writing six or ten lines of code I want to write a loop and only write the part that graphs the data once (where it reads the field from a variable).